# How many elements does the intersection of $n$ circles contain?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

For the real problem that I'm solving is

> For given three circles there are seven elements, then how many elements that 6 circles have?

For the first approche I just draw the picture and count all the elements and get the answer of $31$. But then I wonder what would the $n$ circles contain? So I draw the circle from $2$ circles to $10$ circles and count them all again. I see the pattern of $n(n-1)+1$ elements in $n$ circles, if I'm not wrong. But still, I wonder if one could find it using Algebra. Could someone help please[image]

Comment: I am not understanding the question. How do 3 circles intersect in 7 points? There should only be 6 intersections.

Comment: Do you mean to say that $n$ circles divide the plane into $n(n-1)+1$ _regions_? Like when $n=2$, a Venn diagram has three regions, excluding the outside region?

Comment: @MikeEarnest yes it is something like that. The problem was not in English so I try to translate it into English, and that is what I could come up with

Comment: @PedroAmaral i mean the region it creates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with Euler's formula, $V-E+F=2$, since the arrangement of circles forms a planar graph, where the vertices are intersection points, and the edges are arcs of the circle connecting intersection points. The following analysis assumes that every pair of circles intersects at exactly two points, and no three intersect at a point.

The number of vertices, $V$, is $\binom{n}2\cdot 2$, since there are two intersection points for each pair of circles.

The number of edges, $E$, is $n\cdot 2(n-1)$, since each of the $n$ circles is cut into $2(n-1)$ arcs by the other $n-1$ circles.

Therefore,
$$
F=E-F+2=n\cdot 2(n-1)-2\cdot \binom{n}2+2=n(n-1)+2
$$
Finally, you need to subtract one, since the faces counted by Euler's formula includes the unbounded external face.

Comment: As a consequence one can't draw a Venn-diagram for more the four sets using circles: for four events one gets not $16$ but only $14$ faces.